# Нет модуля django.views.generic.create_update

Tags: views, django

Добрый день!

В документации такой модуль [описывается](http://djbook.ru/rel1.5/ref/generic-views.html#create-update-delete-generic-views), другие надстройки его требуют, но модуля-то такого нет даже в репозитории: https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/views/generic

Как исправить? Почему оно так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если у тебя Django свежая, то следуй рекомендациям использовать Class based views

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/generic-views-migration/

и не путай официальную документацию с djbook.ru

Answer (score 1):

ИСПРАВИЛ:

[Такой модуль есть только в 1.4](https://github.com/django/django/tree/1.4.5/django/views/generic), в 1.5 и выше его уже изъяли, ищите нужный функционал в оставшихся модулях или придётся писать самому. Но скорее всего то, что Вам нужно есть в модуле [Edit](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.1/django/views/generic/edit.py).